# How to use sources from a different subproject in a custom task?

Tags: sbt

I am using sbt 0.13.7.

I guess my question is a bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501897/sbt-custom-task-using-a-class-in-project). I have however a multi-project build.

Let's say my project structure looks like this:

```
- A
   - build.sbt
- B
   - build.sbt
build.sbt
```

and `B.dependsOn(A)`.

Is there a way to write a custom task in `build.sbt` in `B` that uses sources from `A`?

Comment: You need `B.aggregate(A)`? http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#aggregation

Comment: `aggregate` is to let the commands/tasks to be executed in projects specified as aggregated. It sets no classpath dependency. See [Aggregration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation) in the official docs.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `A` and `B` are completely separate builds (it's not just [multi-project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html) as you have several `.sbt` files), it's possible only if your `A` build is physically placed inside `B`.

---

1) If you need A-sources to be available to B-sources:

```
- B
   - build.sbt
   - A
     - build.sbt
build.sbt
```

then you may describe `A`'s sources as some regular `B`'s project , like:

**B/build.sbt**

```
lazy val a = project in "./A"   // or deeply if your sources not in A's root

lazy val b = project in "." dependsOn a
```

**B/A/build.sbt** (if you really need separate build here)

```
lazy val a = project in "."
```

You may want to share some plugin with source-path-independent project definition between `A` and `B` then, like:

```
def a(base: String) = Project(base = base, settings = someAsettings)
```

You may organize such structure with a symlink (Linux/Mac):

```
ln -s ../B A
```

Otherwise you will need to manually publish `A` (`publishLocal`) to your local ivy repository and use it as external dependency.

*If you use Git - symlinks should [be fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link) as long as participants are using same OS. Another solution is git [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).*

---

2) If you need the code from A-sources to be available inside B-build (not B-sources) then you need a structure like this:

```
- B
   - build.sbt
   - project
     - project
       - A  
     build.sbt
```

Project inside project actually becomes an sbt-plugin, so its code is available to B.

If you don't want to change the structure then `A` should became an [`sbt-plugin`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html) and you need to publish it to the local repository.

Comment: I understand. I like alternative A better but it's still a bit to awkward to nest it like this, will probably take the bullet an use an external dependency instead. This is something I was trying to avoid because then I have to release project `A` every time before changes are reflected in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following in `build.sbt` in the top-level root project?

```
lazy val a = project
lazy val b = project

lazy val printSources = taskKey[Unit]("Prints the sources of A")
printSources := {
  println("== sources of A ==")
  (sources in (a, Compile)).value.foreach(println)
}
```

Execute the task `printSources` and you should see the following:

```
[multi-sbt-project]> printSources
== sources of A ==
/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/multi-sbt-project/a/hello.scala
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 18, 2015 11:26:54 AM
```

Comment: is this to copy the sources of `A` into `B`?